# How to recover: Deleted accidently important files

Tags: files, data-recovery

I've accidentally deleted today the `/var/www` with 2 Joomla-Homepages on it. Is there any possibility to recover all these files? I'm using PhotoRec right know, but the recovered files are named like: f3411984.html

I have not create backups, which I should have. I there a better way to recover these files.

Comment: possible duplidate of [Unix/Linux undelete/recover deleted files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files/80285#80285)

Comment: Sorry to hear about this. Take a look at those 2 threads they discuss 2 ways to go. In the mean time shut down the server and pull the drive. Once free space is marked as such on the disk log files and other things can overwrite the space that was used by your data rendering it unrecoverable!