# Recover rc.conf after accidental deletion in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, data-recovery

I'm using FreeBSD 9.1 and I accidentally deleted the file `/etc/rc.conf`.

How can I recover it?

Comment: Might be useful: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files

Answer (score 6):

See `/etc/defaults/rc.conf` for a starting point, customize as you please then backup. :)