# How to recover deleted directories "/home/pi"

Tags: debian, rm

I just deleted my `/home/pi` directory while I was trying to remove the directory under `/home/pi` which was `/home/pi/nmap`.
So, is there anyway to recover `/home/pi` directory as I have other important directories under it.
I use the commmand:

```
rm -rf /home/pi
```

Comment: Restore from your backups. Or, once you have done what you can, start your backup regime....

Comment: I don't consider this as a duplicate because the other question is about a single file. That is a serious difference. The highest ranking answers are special to this case. Deleting a single file and a whole directory is quite a difference. Some of the answers apply here, though.

Comment: yeh.. It was not a duplicate case. Now I cannot even find the previous partition /dev/sda1 (after reboot). Furthermore, it was a home directory of user pi. Thanks @jasonwryan@Hauke Laging

Comment: Maybe [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files) could be helpful i.e. `debugfs` but you must act immediately after the mistake to stop the writes and secure either the disk itself or an image of it...