# Linux: Recovering a deleted dir that another terminal is still cd'ed into

Tags: directory, data-recovery, deleted-files

I accidentally deleted the dir, `/path/to/dir`, and all its contents from an application.

However, I still have a terminal window open, still `cd`-ed in `/path/to/dir`!

**Q: Is there any way to recursively recover `/path/to/dir`?**

Note that `lsof` gives me this:

```
$ lsof | egrep '/path/to'
bash       3113              hs  cwd       DIR              252,0     4096 42207179 /path/to
bash       3487              hs  cwd       DIR              252,0        0 42207253 /path/to/dir (deleted)
```

Further, if I do this...

```
$ ls /proc/3487/fd/
0  1  2  255

$ cd /tmp
$ dd if=/proc/3487/fd/255 of=recovered.dir bs=1M
```

... the `dd` command just sits there doing nothing, with `recovered.dir`'s size not growing. I was assuming here that the process 3487 has the directory `/path/to/dir` open at the file-descriptor 255, and so, if I `dd` or `cat` it, I would be able to recover the entire tree `/path/to/dir`.

There are plenty of articles on the web on how to use `lsof` to recover deleted *regular* files, but none for recovering deleted *directories*.

Would greatly appreciate a quick response!!

Comment: **Stop writing to the disk immediately**. You may have a chance to [recover individual files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files). The files are now fully deleted (as in: the space they occupy is marked as free), but their data may still be lying around. It won't be lying around any more if you overwrite it. Each file is likely to be an independent recovery effort. Better reach for your backups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do what you seek.

While the directory may be held open, the files that reside within the directory are not part of the directory itself. The directory simply stores the file names. In addition to this, with the files having been deleted, the directory has already been modified to remove those files.

In short, unless each individual file is held open, they cannot be recovered in this manner.