# I made a mistake last night, which deleted 1800GB of my File-Server unintentionally

Tags: files, filesystems, rm, tmp

I ran this command yesterday, I thought on a test machine, but it was a File-Server connected through SSH.

```
sudo rm -rf /tmp/* !(lost+found)
```

My terminal emulator is Konsole. My system is Debian 7.

Question:

Did this command delete other files than the files in /tmp?

Comment: Could it be that /home file system is not mounted ?

Comment: @Emmanuel I've confirmed that the files are lost.

Comment: Your history don't shows any deleting errors. You killed many operating system processes while doing the "kill $( lsof /usr ... )". The file system sharing deamon may have been impacted. Did you tried to restart the services or reboot the filer ?

Comment: @somethingSomething Konsole isn't a shell, it is KDE's default terminal emulator. Try to type some characters in the terminal, like `dsgsadfsf` and hit enter. See the result. If it is `bash: dsgsadfsf: command not found`, then your shell is `bash`.

Comment: @GaborFarkas: Or just... `echo $SHELL`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Or just `echo $0` :)

Comment: @GaborFarkas: Didn't know about `echo $0`!  Cool :-D

Comment: **I hope you have good backups.** If you're going to attempt recovery, stop using that system until you are able to make a byte-level copy of the drive to experiment on. Any writes to the file system in question will exacerbate the damage.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The correct syntax in bash is the following:

```
rm /tmp/!(lost+found)
```

As [@goldilocks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/25985/goldilocks) [wrote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167727/i-made-a-mistake-last-night-which-deleted-1800gb-of-my-file-server-unintentiona/167752#comment276083_167742) in the comments, the original command makes an expansion on the query (it deletes all the files in the `/tmp` folder, then goes on, and deletes all the files in the current working folder, in your case the `home` folder).

You can try to check if you can recover some of your data. There is a question about Linux data recovery [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files).

Comment: Ah, so it's essentially another case of the famous "the missing space in my command line that destroyed all my data" - just like in `rm -rf / tmp` ^^

Comment: I can't emphasise enough, that sysadmin paranoia is not causeless. :) Always back up your most valuable data in a place, where you can only write as root.

Comment: I'd rather back up to a separate hard disk or server that is not even writable for root during normal circumstances. OP used `sudo`, so a normal folder only writable for root wouldn't necessarily have helped.

Comment: Good point, I didn't pay enough attention to OP. A server can be costly, however a separate disk is fair enough. I have used a separate partition which was unmounted by default. Simple and dirty, but effective.

Comment: Snapshot-capable filesystems look rather useful even for home environments nowadays. Anyway, best option is a good backup.

Comment: @GaborFarkas That won't stop you from being rooted :)

Comment: @simonzack it can reduce the chance of accidents by mounting it up consequently, it's enough for me :)

Answer (score 26):

The `!(lost+found)` in your `rm` command was probably the fatal mistake:

```
1978  rm -rf /tmp/* !(lost+found)
1979  sudo rm -rf /tmp/* !(lost+found)
```

I don't know exactly what `bash` is doing with that, but this command below prints everything in my `/tmp/` and also everything my current directory (which is currently `~`):

```
echo /tmp/* !(lost+found)
```

Comment: The `!(folder)` is part of a command I once ran, which deleted all except `folder`.

Comment: That sounds like something that might work with zsh; bash I don't think so. I get `!lost+found: event not found` as `!` is used to retrieve commands from the history.

Comment: Yikes! *"I don't know exactly bash is doing with that"* -> it's performing an expansion.  Guess what "everything except this" is? `cd /; echo !(lost+found)` >_<

Comment: @wurtel Try it with the parentheses.

Comment: I did: `$ echo !(xx0091)` `bash: !: event not found`

Comment: Please keep in mind that `!(foo)` works in bash as "all except foo" only if `extglob` option is set. Moreover OP didn't specify which shell he is using, so really hard to guess what exactly `rm !(lost+found)` command has done in his case.

Comment: Great remark, although OP stated he is using Debian 7, which has `bash` as default shell. He most likely didn't change this. Furthermore, in Debian 7, the `extglob` option is set to `true` by default (I just checked this).

Comment: It's also set on fedora, so all in all, would probably be the default on most linux systems.