# Unable to untar file after tar error

Tags: tar, data-recovery, archive

After unsuccessful attempt to make a `tar.gz` file I can't untar the file. It seems like I have lost it and yet this looks like trivial error one should be able to recover from. Is the content of the file really lost? I have tried all sorts of `tar` and `unzip` combinations without success.

**OS environment and tar version:**

```
$cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

$tar --version |grep tar
tar (GNU tar) 1.26
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

```
[weshop@demo test]$ ls
file.txt
[filip@demo test]$ cat file.txt  
hello  

[filip@demo test]$ tar cvzf file.txt file.tar.gz  
tar: file.tar.gz: Cannot stat: No such file or directory  
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors  

[filip@demo test]$ cat file.txt  
 ▒Om7▒▒7▒▒'([filip@demo test]$ 

[filip@demo test]$ tar xvzf file.txt  

[filip@demo test]$ cat file.txt  
 ▒Om7▒▒7▒▒'([filip@  

[filip@demo test]$ file file.txt  
file.txt: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Fri Jul 29 18:48:56 2016  
[filip@demo test]$
```

Comment: `tar cvzf file.tar.gz file.txt` is what you wanted to do at the third step.

Comment: you are trying to create an archive called `file.txt` in that example. The archive name comes before the files you want to add. I am assuming that 'file.txt' has beem overwritten with a gzipped tarball. To test this, run `gzip -d file.txt` and then do `file file.txt`. Alternately if you dont want to replace the gzipped file, do something like `zcat file.txt > file.decompressed` and then check what it is with `file file.decomprrssed`. It is likely to be an empty `tar` archive. You have overwritten `file.txt` due to incorrect use of the `tar` command.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the line

```
$ tar cvzf file.txt file.tar.gz
```

you have asked to create a compressed archive of the file `file.tar.gz`, and that the archive should be called `file.txt`.  You have simply swapped the two filenames around.

The file `file.txt` will be overwritten by an empty compressed `tar` archive. This is why the subsequent commands displays weird things.

Yes, the original contents of `file.txt` is now lost. Sorry. Restore from backup.

See also [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files).