# All my files have been erased after I tried to make my audio better

Tags: kali-linux, deleted-files

I am using Kali Linux 2.0 Debian 64 bit and I was having some problems with Sound output, I went to a certain website which advised me to execute the following
    sudo killall pulseaudio

```
sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio pulseaudio-utils gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio     paman pavumeter pavucontrol

rm ~/ .pulse-cookie  
rm -r ~/ .pulse 

sudo apt-get install alsa-base alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils  alsa-oss alsamixergui libalsaplayer0

apt-get install kmix 

restart

apt-get install pulseaudio and hit enter and and last type apt-get install gnome-core and again hit enter.

reboot
```

And the next thing I see all my bookmarks and files on my hard drive are missing.  Is there anyway I can retrieve them?

Comment: The moral of the story is, don't execute commands you don't understand.

Answer (score 6):

your mistake is here:

```
rm -r ~/ .pulse
```

there were no space between `~/` and `.pulse` on this website I believe.

So, you effectively deleted all files in directory `~/` (your home directory) and in sub-directory `.pulse` of a current directory.

It is a hard job to restore your files. Check that answer please: [Unix/Linux undelete/recover deleted files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files)

Comment: root@kali:~# debugfs -w /root/Documents
debugfs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
/root/Documents: Is a directory while opening filesystem
debugfs:  lsdel
lsdel: Filesystem not open

Comment: @beegeeAssem There's little chance that you'll be able to recover files this way anyway. Restore from your latest backup.