# Resizing luks encrypted partition to fill free space

Tags: filesystems, partition, luks

I'm trying to use the full space available on my HDD (1TB, migrating from 500GB HDD).My partition is encrypted (LUKS).

I tried based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320957/extend-a-luks-encrypted-partition-to-fill-disk), however `lvresize` seems to be not extending my partition to ~ 1TB:

```
sudo lvresize -l+100%FREE /dev/mapper/vg_oc2462701832-lv_root
  Size of logical volume vg_oc2462701832/lv_root unchanged from 449.47 GiB (115065 extents).
  Logical volume vg_oc2462701832/lv_root successfully resized.
```

My setup:

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00078ba5

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048    2050047    2048000  1000M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       2050048 1953521663 1951471616 930.5G 83 Linux

sudo vgs -o +vg_free_count,vg_extent_count
  VG              #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree   Free   #Ext  
  vg_oc2462701832   1   1   0 wz--n- 930.53g 481.06g 123151 238216
```

I've also tried to use the [blivet-gui](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Blivet-gui)  to resize the LVM (from Fedora 26 live CD), like this:

[image: resize]

resulting in following actions:

[image: resize action]

I get the following error:

[image: err]

**UPDATE**:

```
sudo vgdisplay vg_oc2462701832
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg_oc2462701832
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  14
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               930.53 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              238216
  Alloc PE / Size       115065 / 449.47 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       123151 / 481.06 GiB
  VG UUID               3HqxOa-RJb1-aQAr-C5fl-w5Vj-mEE9-ukZbqC
```

moreover:

```
sudo pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/luks-1da0b326-4b3f-4e7c-8319-908f0fa745d4
  VG Name               vg_oc2462701832
  PV Size               930.53 GiB / not usable 1.00 MiB
  Allocatable           NO
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              238216
  Free PE               123151
  Allocated PE          115065
  PV UUID               J8pq9i-HkjC-Ch1s-bo4p-ejvQ-FB5q-w3wtax
```

Comment: Can you ceate an additional LV in that VG? Does `lvresize -l+1` work? Is there anything in the output of `dmesg`?

Comment: `sudo lvresize -l+1 /dev/mapper/vg_oc2462701832-lv_root` results in: `Insufficient free space: 1 extents needed, but only 0 available`

Comment: creating additional LV doesn't work as well. Tried with blivet-gui, it resulted in: `Insufficient free space: ... extends needed, but only 0 available`.

Comment: Create a backup of the LVM metadata with `vgcfgbackup` and check whether its data is correct (especially the PV size).

Comment: What have you done so far? Did you copy the LUKS volume to the new disk and then enlarge it with `cryptsetup resize`, or did you create a new encrypted volume and copy the LVM PV? What is the output of `vgdisplay vg_oc2462701832` and of `pvdisplay` on the physical volume?

Comment: @Gilles outputs provided. I did a copy of disk to disk with clonezilla and afterwards followed the: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320957/extend-a-luks-encrypted-partition-to-fill-disk up to step 9, where output I provided (and was suspicious, as no additional space was available)

Comment: @HaukeLaging I ran `sudo  vgcfgbackup` with output: `Volume group "vg_oc2462701832" successfully backed up.` but not sure how to check whether it's data is correct :(

Comment: What's the output of `lvs`? It displays various attributes of the logical volumes.

Comment: There is a block `physical_volumes {`. What is the `dev_size = ` value it contains?