# extend encrypted system partion

Tags: disk-encryption, volume

I have a system using luks encryption and I want to extend the system partition. Seems to look like [Extend a LUKS encrypted partition to fill disk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320957/extend-a-luks-encrypted-partition-to-fill-disk), but a bit different.
Because my physical disk seems already to be extended to 40g but the encrypted volume stays 18g. 
Here some info:

```
lvs
root mint-vg  -wi-a---- 18.10g
swap mint-vg  -wi-a----  1.41g

pvs
/dev/mapper/crypt-volume mint-vg lvm2 a-- 19.52g 0 PFree

lsblk
sda                     8:0  0    40G 0 disk
|-sda2                  8:2  0     1k 0 part
|-sda5                  8:5  0  19.5G 0 part
| |-crypt-volume      253:0  0  19.5G 0 crypt
|   |-mint--vg-root   253:1  0  18.1G 0 lvm 
|   |-mint--vg-swap_1 253:2  0   1.4G 0 lvm
|-sda1                  8:1  0   487M 0 part
```

What do I need to do to make use of the full 40G disk space of /dev/sda for crypt volume /dev/sda5?

Comment: Hello welcome on stackexchange, please next time try to do the minimum of formatting so your question is readable ;-)

Comment: Is that an extended partition wedged between two primary ones? Output of `parted /dev/sda unit s print free`? What's on sda1 and sda2?