# How to extend an encryted partition? (Kali linux)

Tags: kali-linux, luks

My encrypted partition is full. How can I extend it step by step please?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This **extremely** much sounds like you haven't heeded the advise https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/ . Kali is not meant to be used as general purpose OS. They say so themselves, for good reason.

Answer (score 0):

- Boot from a live CD like [system-rescue](https://www.system-rescue.org/Download/) and use gparted to extend the parttion to the left.
- then you can extended the upper layer which is luks, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320957/extend-a-luks-encrypted-partition-to-fill-disk) for example
- and then the filesystem (ext3)

Comment: You can't just "extend a partition to the left"; that doesn't put the superblock of the LVM physical volume at the beginning of the partition, so LVM will then not be able to find that partition.

Comment: Not sure, as for the partition level I'm pretty sure gparted can do it. as for the LVM ... I don't see him using LVM based on the picture above, but from what I can remember pvresize also should work, but I never used it to "extend to the left"