# how can i get bashrc file if it deleted in linux

Tags: fedora

I have deleted my bashrc file originally .how can i retrieve it.

when i use `vi .~/bashrc` command.

```
".~/bash.rc" E212: Can't open file for writing
screen does look like above
```

Comment: The title question is answered in [this question about data recovery](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files), but the error at the end is because you have mistyped the path (it should be `~/.bashrc`); I'm not sure which one you actually mean to ask.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc
```