# After the edit of ~/.bashrc file: ll command not found

Tags: permissions, bashrc

I was installing Hadoop on my Ubuntu.

This is my PATH now

```
echo $PATH
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin:/home/miki/.local/bin:/opt/hadoop-3.2.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

If I try `ll`

```
miki@miki:~$ ll
ll: command not found
```

My bashrc edit line

```
echo 'export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.2.0;export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$PATH' > ~/.bashrc
```

the ~/.bashrc file has only one line

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.2.0
```

All previous scripts were deleted.

It is also strange that letters have changed the color.
Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using `... > ~/.bashrc`, you have replaced the content with just the `echo` output.

So you removed all the other content of your `.bashrc` file. You can recover the default `.bashrc` with.

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

Then run your command again, but make sure to use `>>` instead of `>` to append to the file instead of replacing it.

[See also.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334726/how-can-i-get-bashrc-file-if-it-deleted-in-linux)