# How do I recover the contents of a file?

Tags: command-line, files, data-recovery

I accidentally executed `man ls > info.txt` and now I don't know how to recover the contents of the file.

Comment: Unless you have a backup somewhere, you're SOL. Sorry.

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80270/117549

Comment: @JeffSchaller those links are about delete/undelete entire files, not about content of them.

Comment: But is it still in RAM or swap? If yes, it won’t be for long. Search for a combination of words present in your old file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've wrote the output of "`man ls`" command in a file that you called it "`info.txt`".
If your info.txt file was empty, now easily you can delete your file and create new one by using these commands:

```
#rm -f info.txt
#vi info.txt
```

(then<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and press yes to save it.)

Or:

you can open `info.txt` file, and delete content of it.
for example, if you use "`nano`" editor, you can follow steps:

```
# nano info.txt  
#ctrl+k
(pressing ctrl+k on each line) 
#ctrl+x 
save your edition.
```

But if your `info.txt` file had something before overwriting, unfortunately you can't retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're hoping to recover the contents of info.txt, I'm sorry but you're SOL -- that data has been overwritten by the output of the `man` command. Not just deleted, which *can* sometimes be recovered, but overwritten, which generally *can't* without a professional (IE, law enforcement forensics or higher grade) data recovery setup.