# How to recover xfs data after rm?

Tags: data-recovery, xfs

Is it possible to recover files that have been rm'ed from an XFS filesystem? How can I recover any files assuming they haven't been overwritten?

Edit:
The existing questions regarding this topic are all assuming an ext{2,3,4} file system. I am looking for an XFS solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unix/Linux undelete/recover deleted files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files)

Comment: Those provided answers are only for ext{2,3,4} file systems. That is why I have specified XFS filesystem.

Comment: Restore from a backup

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I deleted a python file that I knew had a specific fairly unique string in it.  So I did the following:

```
$ sudo strings -td /dev/mapper/vg01-lv_opt | grep "class Team("
8648365228 class Team(object):
26133651864 class Team(Account):
26134147482 class Team(Account):
```

I now had the offsets in the lvol where that string was.  I then did a dd around that area to recover the text:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/mapper/vg01-lv_opt of=/tmp/recover skip=26134140000 count=1M bs=1
```

...then I brought that smaller file into vi and trimmed around the file, and voila!  I had my content back.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me! After hours of searching this worked the first time, thank you friend!!!!!

Answer (score 11):

Because the methods from the XFS FAQ page did not work for me, I wrote a tiny recovery tool myself.

**[xfs_undelete](https://github.com/ianka/xfs_undelete)**

It recovered the 60 video files I accidentally mv'ed on top of each other instead of a subdir. Please comment on the tool at the github bug tracker.

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of investigation, it looks like there is no official method but several methods are listed on the official [XFS FAQ](http://xfs.org/index.php/XFS_FAQ#Q:_Does_the_filesystem_have_an_undelete_capability.3F) page