# How may I recover a lost pdf file?

Tags: files, data-recovery, pdf

I accidentally lost a pdf file during the following process

- I was  running a pdf software application PDFXCView in Wine in Ubuntu 18.04, to open a pdf file in a ext4 filesystem.
- Then I `mv` the pdf file somewhere else.
- Then I edited the pdf file already opened in PDFXCView. When I tried to save the edited file,  I had to choose "save as..." to locate the current path of the file and attempted to overwrite it. But PDFXCView failed to overwrite the file,   furthermore made it disappear and then aborted
  .

Here are some attempts.

1. If it can be helpful, I remember the pathname of the lost pdf file.
2. I couldn't backup the partition of the filesystem  by `dd`, since I
   don't have an additional hard drive with big enough capacity for the
   partition.
3. I tried `debugfs` according to
   https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80285,

   ```
    $ sudo debugfs -w /dev/sda4
    debugfs: lsdel

    Inode  Owner  Mode    Size      Blocks   Time deleted
   22549259   1000 100600    141      1/     1 Sat Apr  2 09:14:06 2016
   1 deleted inodes found.

   debugfs:  logdump -i 22549259
   22549259: File not found by ext2_lookup
   ```

   The file was just lost instead of being deleted in 2016, so I am not
   sure if it found the correct inode.
4. I saw in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/98700/ that says using

   ```
   grep -a -C 500 'known pattern' /dev/sda | tee /tmp/recover
   ```

   to recover a text file which contains a known pattern.

   A while ago, I created the lost pdf file by concatenating several
   smaller pdf files using `pdftk` and I still have those smaller
   files.  From one smaller pdf file, I can  see the binary content of a smaller pdf file by `cat smaller.pdf | less`, which contains a readable pdf format specific string

   ```
   /URI (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.logger)
   ```

   So I tried:

   ```
   sudo grep -a -C 500 'http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0' /dev/sda4 >  /tmp/test/recover
   ```

   Because those small files and the lost file both contain the string, and    `-C 500` is too arbitrary to specify the begin and end of a file.  I am not sure it can produce useful results.

I was wondering what ways I may try to recover the pdf file?

Thanks!

Comment: Since it sounds like the pdf is very important, don't play around, unmount the partion if you can (if not, hopefully you have a live usb lying around) and then proceed with `magicrescue` I will put the steps for it in the answer below

Answer (score 8):

Definitely start with leaving the partition with the data alone, if at all possible (you would be surprised what you can recover even a month later if it is not your main system partition). Then proceed with [`foremost`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man8/foremost.8.html) (I originally mentioned `magicrescue` but `foremost` performs just as well, yet it has a ready receipe for `pdf`

```bsh
sudo apt update && sudo apt install foremost
sudo foremost -v -t pdf -i [PATH] -o ~/pdfrecovery/

# -t - Filetype [in our case pdf]
# -i - Input file [can be as wide as /dev/sdX or more detailed]
# -o - Output Directory
```

I just ran it for a few seconds on one of my `/dev/sdX` drives and pulled 370 pdf files. The files will have no original names and will look like this: `14348984.pdf` so the `-i` flag is pretty important.

Good luck.

---

### Update

Your second option is `testdisk`/`photorec` which in your case may be easier when dealing with the known path. `testdisk` and `photorec` do have some caveats that if not careful (and happen to confirm multiple dialogs asking if you want to apply changes) can lead to disk damage, but it you take it slow, it may be more appropriate, and faster as it will likely show you a good folder tree structure with a node corresponding to your missing file. If you do not find your file with `foremost` in let's say 2 hours, post a comment and I will provide a secondary `testdisk` approach.

### Update 2

When I just tested it, `testdisk` crushed `foremost` in terms of locating a specific deleted file. It preserved the folder tree and filename structure perfectly, thus limiting the time spent creating every `*.pdf` file. The two approaches differ substantially, and if the file is very important, I would definitely use both `testdisk` and `foremost` to locate the same file to be sure I end up with a full non-corrupted file.

Comment: Thanks. (1)  If I don't unmount the partition (my /home partition) or remount it readonly, can I run foremost? Is the risk only that  some processes may write to the partition? Will foremost write to the partition? (2) If I know the time window in which the file became lost, can I specify that to foremost?

Comment: (3) does `-i` specify the full pathname of the  directory which contained the lost file? Or has to be the partition  that contained the lost file, which is `/dev/sda4` in my case?

Comment: (4) does it recover all the pdf files including those that are not deleted, or just recover deleted pdf files?

Comment: 1) Yes, no need to unmount it but it is always better. 2) no, there is no time indexing as far as I know 3) i have only used it either on partitions or  `.dd` files of partitions. I am not sure if you can actually use it on for example `~/Downloads/*` because `foremost` scans blocks and looks for the particular headers and footers 4) it recovers ALL pdf files, because it is meant and often used for damaged partitions where files may be inaccessible but not "deleted" per se. If you know the size of the pdf then you can run a secondary script on the -o` directory.

Comment: actually if you know some specific part/excerpt of the pdf in question then you can run foremost and then for every new pdf file found in the directory specified with  `-o` you can use `pdftotext`and then grep for some specific word

Comment: Thanks. (1) I am running it and it will take a long time to create all the files, and I manually run pdfgrep to search among the directory. I was wondering how to automatically run pdfgrep once a new file is created by foremost, or delete a file if it doesn't contain the specific string?  (I now store the recovered files in /tmp under my root partition which has limited unused space. (2)  I am also trying ext3grep and have some questions. I'd appreciate if you could consider https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564231/does-ext3grep-work-on-ext4

Comment: Thanks for update. Do you have some links for recommended usage of testdisk and photorec? Do I have to umount the filesystem that  contains the lost file before using them? Is photorec only for recovering image files not pdf files?

Comment: Could you elaborate how you used "testdisk/photorec which in your case may be easier when dealing with the known path" and "When I just tested it, testdisk crushed foremost in terms of locating a specific deleted file"? Can they  recover  files only in a given pathname?

Comment: 1) `photorec` is not just for photos, but all types of files. However, it again tends to pull from `.dd` and other image files or partitions. 2) `testdisk` on the other hand is primarily designed for scanning and repairing of partitions but it allows for remarkable recovery of deleted files as well. If you would like I can walk you throughyour issue with `testdisk` , just give me 5 minutes to finish eating and we can move to chat in the meantime make sure you have `testdisk` installed etc.

Comment: If you could let me know how you use testdisk, given the original pathname of the lost file, the time window of the deletion and the type of the file (pdf). That would be great

Comment: Do I have to umount the filesystem that contains the lost file before using using testdisk and phtorec? (My laptop doesn't recognize my bootable flash drive, so I haven't figured out how to umount my /home filesystem)

Comment: Ok, I'm back I'll open a chat window and walk you through it

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/103751/how-may-i-recover-a-lost-pdf-file?tab=general

Comment: "Only users nominated by the room owner may talk here"

Comment: we moved to https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103752/