# How to avoid file loss when moving a file while editing it in a program?

Tags: files, data-recovery

Consider the following sequence of actions:

- I instruct a program to open a file,
- (I modify the file in the program, and save it to the file. )
- I `mv` the file elsewhere. For example, the file was originally `dir1/dir2/dir3/all.pdf`, and then I ran `mv dir1/dir2/dir3 dir1/;  rmdir dir1/dir2`. Now the file is `dir1/dir3/all.pdf`.
- I modify the file in the program
- I instruct the program to save the modified to the new location of the file, via "save as ...".

Is whether  "save as ..." with file moving succeeds or fails up to the program?
For example,

- [when the program is PDFXCView run under wine 3.0 and Ubuntu 18.04](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564219/how-may-i-recover-a-lost-pdf-file/564222), it  made a pdf file disappear and aborted its own process, when "save as...".
- Can a program native to Linux fail "save as ..." and lose the file, or fail "save as..." and keep the file intact, or succeed in "save as ..."?

While another program moves files, what does a program need to do to save  changes to the files successfully (either to the new location or the original one)?

Does the OS or filesystem not be able to warn or prevent such cases from happening?

What can we do to avoid or reduce the likelihood of data loss, in such cases, regardless of which program, OS or filesystem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Can a program native to Linux fail "save as ..." and lose the file, or fail "save as..." and keep the file intact, or succeed in "save as ..."?

In GNU/Linux, if a file is open by any program, it will be loaded into memory. If you moved or even delete the file in the disk, it will still be in memory. When you save it again, it would be saved from memory to disk again. Some programs would even notify you about the deleting and prompt you to **save as** or **ignore**, e.g. `kate`. Other operating systems or emulation software vary in this behavior.

To get more technical knowledge on how this works in GNU/Linux read [this](https://www.linux.com/news/bring-back-deleted-files-lsof/)

Comment: Thanks. I got notifications in my case. PDFXCView in wine notified me that it can't save to the original location. So I tried save as .... to the new location. It also notified me it can't save as ... to the new location, and furthermore surprisingly make the file at the new location disappear.

Comment: @StackExchangeforAll: wine and windows has completely different behavior due to a *limitation* in their architecture, but who cares ;)

Comment: Do you mean the cause of my file loss is wine not the application PDFXCView?

Comment: @StackExchangeforAll: It could be both. I don't use wine or any Windows software but you can answer this question yourself by trying libreoffice e.g. If it faces the same problem, then the _limitation_ is in Wine/Windows. BTW, when I say _limitation_, it's my view point. They may argue it's **by design** so you don't need to ask your question