# Help make sense of xfs_logprint output

Tags: data-recovery, xfs, journaling

I recently came across this thread about recovering file in linux:
[Recover deleted files on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/recover-deleted-files-on-linux?newreg=730421afa5ef4cb3b2e42f5ea038c543). After consulting the top answer which describes recovering in the ext file system family, I wanted to try and apply the same logic, but to the XFS file system.

I found the xfs_logprint command, which I believe will should act as replacement to the logdump inside debugfs. But when I used it on my device, I could't make sense of the output. I have some ideas as to what it means, but I cannot find sources on the internet that'll help me make sense of it.

for example, here's a section from the output

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oper (2): tid: 15f207c3  len: 24  clientid: TRANS  flags: none
BUF:  #regs: 2   start blkno: 0 (0x0)  len: 1  bmap size: 1  flags: 0x9000
Oper (3): tid: 15f207c3  len: 384  clientid: TRANS  flags: none
SUPER BLOCK Buffer:
icount: 6360863066640355328  ifree: 976558  fdblks: 0  frext: 0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

With this being one of many.

Does anybody know where I could find more information about the format of the journal?